# get only first row matches a specific string - R

Tags: r, grepl, stringi

I have a tibble in R.

```
        tibble [9,760,576 x 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)

 $ word: chr [1:9760576] "dont know" "years ago" "im sure" "years old" ...
 $ n   : int [1:9760576] 7240 5127 5068 5017 ...
```

Executing the following code gets the rows matching the specific pattern (rows starting with "year").

I'm interested only in the **first row** matching the pattern, so I need to stop the search after the first occurrence. Any suggestion is welcome.

```
df %>% filter(grepl("^year", word))
# A tibble: 17,117 x 2
   word            n
   <chr>       <int>
 1 years ago    5127
 2 year old     2444
 3 years old    1692
 4 years later  1103
 5 years now     758
 6 year ago      608
 7 year will     409
 8 years since   395
 9 year year     325
10 years ive     303
```

The problem I have is the performance, the original dataset has 100 Millions rows and takes too much time.

Also I tried with `stringi` package but same issue (I cannot stop the search after finding the first occurrence)

```
stri_match_first_regex(df$word, pattern="^year",
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Typical R functions are built on vectorization and operating on whole vectors at once. Functions like `match()` are designed to stop at the first hit, but I think any functions to do regex will be designed to operate on whole vectors. I think you'd need to turn to Rcpp to write a custom solution that applies regex to elements one at a time and stops at the first hit.